# How do I change a class from factor to date, with large amounts of data?

Tags: r, plot, acoustics

I'm trying to plot the data for fish detection's but we have several million data points.

I did: `plot (Data.df$dates, Data.df$ID == "1")` to try to give me the presence of the fish but instead of dates the x axis was:

[image]

I want to change the numbers on the x values to display as dates.

If I enter dput(head(data.df)) it gives my dates as "2020-07-03 06:51:25" format but class is a factor.

We had 90 fish so what I was trying to do here was display each the dates where the fish were detected as true and once they had been caught I was thinking they would display as false so the line would move up to the top permanently and I could work out what date the fish was caught.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us the format of your data please? If you type `dput(head(Data.df))` into the console, then press "edit" under your question and paste the result in, it should be easy to get an answer for you. Without this, we can only guess how to fix your problem.

Comment: Try as.Date() https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/as.Date.

you can also specify the desired format

Comment: If you have several million data points I would not recommend reformating the column as date. As far as I understand, you only need the x-axis as dates. You can do this with a custom axis you can draw with the function `axis()`. Just suppress the original axis with the parameter `xaxt="n"` and create a custom axis with the correct dates.